# Port 8080 (tomcat7) wont connect from outside the localhost computer

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I am running tomcat7 but I don't think there is an issue with the setup.
I can connect to port 8080 from the local machine.  I cannot connect to 8080 from other computers on the network.
There is no firewall running.

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::7877                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

```
nmap localhost 
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

```
nmap server (from different computer)
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
80/tcp  open   http
443/tcp closed https
```

```
There is no firewall running
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Everything I see says firewall is problem, but there is no firewall running.
Port 80 is visible externally but port 8080 is not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using? Desktop or server installation?

Comment: Which firewall are you using if you use `ufw`, [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1478625/edit) and add the output of `sudo ufw status`. While you are editing your question, add the OS and version number in your question as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.